# want to change text and image and sound when click "next" image in the same view

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onclick

want to change text and image and sound when click "next"  image in the same view

i have database and activity with array list 
i want to shange text and image and sound when click "next"
i want to shange text and image and sound when click "prev"

i have add release cod but error show in this row
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);

show image to show whate i mean

xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/back2"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/prev"
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/ddd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:src="@drawable/next"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:text="ddfhhhhhhf"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:src="@drawable/play"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagee"
                android:src="@drawable/pink"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/prev"
                android:src="@drawable/prev"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

model

```
public class AlwanarModel {

//int voicRecourceID;
private int mAlwanarRecourceID;

private String mTextAlwanar;

private int mAudioAlwanarResourceId;

public AlwanarModel(int mAlwanarRecourceID, String mTextAlwanar, int mAudioAlwanarResourceId) {
    this.mAlwanarRecourceID = mAlwanarRecourceID;
    this.mTextAlwanar = mTextAlwanar;
    this.mAudioAlwanarResourceId = mAudioAlwanarResourceId;
}

public int getmAlwanarRecourceID() {
    return mAlwanarRecourceID;
}

public void setmAlwanarRecourceID(int mAlwanarRecourceID) {
    this.mAlwanarRecourceID = mAlwanarRecourceID;
}

public String getmTextAlwanar() {
    return mTextAlwanar;
}

public void setmTextAlwanar(String mTextAlwanar) {
    this.mTextAlwanar = mTextAlwanar;
}

public int getmAudioAlwanarResourceId() {
    return mAudioAlwanarResourceId;
}

public void setmAudioAlwanarResourceId(int mAudioAlwanarResourceId) {
    this.mAudioAlwanarResourceId = mAudioAlwanarResourceId;
}
}
```

activity java

```
public class AlwanarabicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int index = 0;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
ImageView image,prev,next,play;
TextView text;

public MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // Now that the sound file has finished playing, release the media player resources.
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};


private void showAlwanar(AlwanarModel current){
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(current.getmAlwanarRecourceID()));
    text.setText(current.getmTextAlwanar());
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,  current.getmAudioAlwanarResourceId());
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    final ActivityAlwanarabicBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_alwanarabic);


        final ArrayList<AlwanarModel> arrayAlwanarList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel ( R.drawable.blacke, "اسود",R.raw.aswad));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel ( R.drawable.green, "اخضر",R.raw.akdar));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.blue,"ازرق",R.raw.azraq));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.pink,"وردي",R.raw.wardy));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.red,"احمر",R.raw.ahmar));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.yallow,"اصفر",R.raw.asfar));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.brown,"بني",R.raw.bny));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.gray,"رمادي",R.raw.ramady));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.cyan,"ازرق سماوي",R.raw.azrk_smawy));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.orange,"برتقالي",R.raw.brtoqaly));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.purple,"بنفسجي",R.raw.banafsgyy));
        arrayAlwanarList.add(new AlwanarModel (R.drawable.white,"ابيض",R.raw.abyd));


        image = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imagee);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        next = (ImageView)findViewById( R.id.next);
        prev = (ImageView)findViewById( R.id.prev);
        play = (ImageView)findViewById( R.id.play);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // check if index is not at the last item in arraylist
                if(index < arrayAlwanarList.size()-1){

                    //increase index to next one
                    index++;
                    // Get the current Alwanar and display
                    showAlwanar(arrayAlwanarList.get(index));

                }
                if(index == arrayAlwanarList.size()-1){

                    //increase index to next one
                    index=0 ;
                    // Get the current Alwanar and display
                    showAlwanar(arrayAlwanarList.get(0));
                }
            }
        });



        prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /// check if index is not at the first item in arraylist
                if(index > 0 ){

                    //increase index to next one
                    index--;
                    // Get the current Alwanar and display
                    showAlwanar(arrayAlwanarList.get(index));

                }

            }
        });


    showAlwanar(arrayAlwanarList.get(index));
}
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
        // because we no longer need it.
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
        // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
        // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create new method in Activity like this:

```
private void showAlwanar(AlwanarModel current){
  image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(current.getmAlwanarRecourceID()));
  text.setText(current.getmTextAlwanar());
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,  current.getmAudioAlwanarResourceId());
  mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Then under onClick method you call the method like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

      // check if index is not at the last item in arraylist
      if(index < arrayAlwanarList.size()-1){
         //increase index to next one
         index++;

         // Get the current Alwanar and display
         showAlwanar(arrayAlwanarList.get(index));
       }


    }
```

Then in onCreate() load the first Alwanar when the app starts like this:

```
showAlwanar(arrayAlwanarList.get(index));
```

For showing previous Alwanar:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

      // check if index is not at the first item in arraylist
      if(index > 0){
         // decrease index to point to previous Alwanar in list
         index--;

         // Get the current Alwanar and display
         showAlwanar(arrayAlwanarList.get(index));
       }


    }
```

Comment: its done good coge     but preve image to set the previous sound and text and image ??

Comment: I have added code to set previous Alwanar. Kindly upvote if the code works. Thanks

Comment: i ad release to sound but give me error in thes row                                                   mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);                                               when ad under                                                                                                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,  current.getmAudioAlwanarResourceId());
        mediaPlayer.start();

Comment: i modify the cod up please chick